# Non Kähler complex algebraic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Is there an example of a smooth complex algebraic variety whose underlying complex manifold is not Kähler?

Comment: See [Hironaka's example.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hironaka%27s_example#A_complete_abstract_variety_that_is_not_projective)